# How to trigger a color inversion effect for one window?

Tags: xorg, compiz

I want to have an inverse color effect (light to dark)  like 'negative' in compiz, but without compiz, and only for one window (like compiz's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) .

Is there a way to get a similar effect (toggled by a key combo preferably) without compiz?  I can invert colors for the entire desktop with `xcalib -I -a`, but I can't restrict it to a single window.

Comment: Maybe related to this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/invert-colors-of-the-active-window

Comment: i've been using the negative window option from compiz window manager and it works very well also.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know... to achieve that, you will need help of a [Window Compositor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager).
You can try to install a lightweight standalone compositor like [Compton](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/README.md).

### Compton

> Compton is a lightweight compositor for X, and a fork of
>   xcompmgr-dana.

According to the [Man Pages](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/man/compton.1.asciidoc) Compton has an option to invert colors in a window.

e.g:

```
compton --invert-color-include <CONDITION>
```

The condition could be the **WM_CLASS** of a window, to find the "WM_CLASS" in a window you can run the command [xprop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xprop.1.html)

- `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`

Then the cursor will be a **"Cross"** and you can click in the window you want, to find the WM_CLASS.

Now you should have something like this:

> WM_CLASS(STRING) = "leafpad", "Leafpad"

[image]

The second string should be the WM_CLASS **"Leafpad"**.
So, to invert the colors of the Leafpad editor you should run:

- `compton --invert-color-include 'class_g="Leafpad"'`

In some cases, you might want to invert only some windows of a program (e.g. invert the editor window, but not the "save file" dialog).
For that you can use the *first* of the two `WM_CLASS` strings (also called the "instance"):

- `compton --invert-color-include '(class_g="Leafpad" && class_i="leafpad")'`

You do not need to run compton all the time, you can run it when you need to invert the colors of a window.

---

**NOTE:** *In this example I'm running Lubuntu 13.04 with openbox as window manager but without compositor by default.*

---

### To install Compton

This compositor has it own [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~richardgv/+archive/compton)

**1)** To install compton open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:richardgv/compton`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compton`

In this example I will create a basic Bash script *(I am not an expert in scripts)* to detect the active window and invert its colors.

**2)** Create the script.

- `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
- `mkdir ~/Scripts`
- `nano ~/Scripts/invert.sh`

The content of the script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$(pidof compton)" ];
    then
            pkill compton
    else

        ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
        CLASS=$(xprop -id "$ID"  | grep "WM_CLASS" | awk '{print $4}')
        COND="class_g=${CLASS}"
        compton --invert-color-include "$COND" &
fi
exit
```

---

> Basically  the script will check if compton is running, if it not
>   running xdotool will find the window id of the active window, with the id xprop will find
>   the WM_CLASS, then with the WM_CLASS it will create the condition and
>   finally will run compton with the condition as argument.

Make the script executable.

- `chmod +x ~/Scripts/invert.sh`

In my case I will create a soft link to the /usr/bin/ directory with the name **"invert-color"**

- `sudo ln -s ~/Scripts/invert.sh /usr/bin/invert-color`

**3)** create a Keyboard Shortcut 
e.g:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> *(In Lubuntu you should edit the lubuntu-rc.xml file)*

- `leafpad ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

Add the following Lines:

> ```
> <!-- Launch invert-color activewindow on Ctrl + Alt + U-->
> <keybind key="C-A-U">
>   <action name="Execute">
>     <command>invert-color</command>
>   </action>
> </keybind>
> ```

Finally you can Logout and Login to see the changes in the keyboard shortcut.

---

My intention is when I need to invert the colors in the active window I can do it with the Shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.If I want to go back to the normal colors I will press again the shortcut and the script will detect the compton is running therefore the pkill command will kill the process compton.
So in this way I will only run the compositor when I need it.

Here you have a few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Any way to make this work if a window is full screen as well? This may be desireable when switching between different workspaces.

Comment: @Toothrot already works as advertised on my system (using i3wm and that exact same script from the answer)

Comment: And finally found the time to scratch that itch: To **actually** only invert one window (instead of say ALL your browser windows, like the above does), just use `COND="client=${ID}"`

Comment: The script you provided (`invert.sh`) does the work on Ubuntu 18.04, nevertheless when you work on a dual screen layout it flickers, then commits the colors inversion. Thumbs up for a simple and good solution. This works pretty fine when we can't use `xcalib -i -a` to do this task. I faced a kind of issue with composition when using an Intel embedded GPU on my Laptop. And been looking for a solution for several weeks since. Just in case somebody faced the same situation, this does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Roman, I found a way to avoid restarting compton, turns out it has dbus support - https://askubuntu.com/a/1486007/10263

Answer (score 2):

A Gnome Shell Extension "Invert Window Color" does this without any hassle. Here is the [Link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1041/invert-window-color/).

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Kubuntu/KDE Plasma, you can go to Workspace Behaviour>Desktop Effects>Accessibility and activate "Invert".

Then the key command Ctrl+Meta+U will invert the active window.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Raguet's answer is good, but there is a way to avoid restarting compton. Upon checking the sources, I found there is a field called `invert_color_force` which is set by D-Bus.

```
  /// Override value of window color inversion state. Set by D-Bus method
  /// calls.
  switch_t invert_color_force;
```

In fact, there is a color inverter script in the examples in their official repo - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chjj/compton/master/dbus-examples/inverter.sh

So simply download that script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chjj/compton/master/dbus-examples/inverter.sh
chmod +x inverter.sh
```

and start compton with the `--dbus` flag:

```
compton --dbus
```

After that you can switch the window using this:

```
inverter.sh focused
```

I added it to my openbox rc as a shortcut:

```
<keybind key="C-A-M">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>inverter.sh focused</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```