# list existing X display names?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

How do I get a list of current X display names?

Apart from being a useful thing to know, I want this so that (hopefully!) I can use `xcalib -invert -alter` as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181419/how-to-reverse-colors-for-the-current-window-in-gnome-shell) to invert the second of two screens on my computer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
w
```

Yeah, that simple. That's an expanded version of `who` which shows who is logged in, and where they're connected from. That includes graphical sessions and that will show you all the current X displays, amongst other delicious data.

Here's what I see:

```
oli@bert:~$ w
 01:07:38 up 5 days, 58 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.37, 0.41
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
oli      tty7     :0               Sat00    5days  4:22m  0.94s gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
oli      pts/4    :0               Sat00   47:09m  0.77s  0.77s /bin/bash
oli      pts/6    :0               Wed02    0.00s  0.12s  0.00s w
```

You can file that down with various flags (try `-hs`) and then you can `awk`/`grep` away at that if you need to automate. Consider piping the resulting list through `sort -u` to get unique display strings. Something like this:

```
oli@bert:~$ w -hs | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
:0
```

Comment: wonderful! I thought it would be simple, didn't expect a single character command though ;)  Unfortunately it doesn't solve my xcalib problem though - I'll ask it in another quesion.

Comment: I added a xcalib question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230870/xcalib-i-a-controls-only-one-of-two-screens-can-it-control-both) in case you're interested.

Comment: with KDE I'm getting `username        :0                        ?xdm?  /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkde` as the first line, so `?xdm?` gets shown instead of `:0`. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Nitpick: It seems this won't pick up X displays that aren't logged into, such as the X display used by a GDM login screen.  These can be found a bit messily via searching processes, e.g. `ps aux | grep X`, but you separately need `w` or `who` to see the displays used by logged in users, it seems.

Comment: No need for sort. `w -hs | awk '!u[$3]++{print $3}'` :P