# How to know which processes have the DISPLAY variable set?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

Sometimes I face some problems in display and mostly I do want to know which files or processes are using the DISPLAY environment variable.

So how to list all processes that having DISPLAY set?

Answer (score 15):

I came up to this command after many searches and tries:

```
for file in /proc/[0-9]*; do grep -ao 'DISPLAY=[^[:cntrl:]]*' $file/environ 2>/dev/null && grep -ao '(.*)' $file/stat; done | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
```

A sample of the output is:

```
DISPLAY=:0  (unity-files-dae)
DISPLAY=:0  (unity-music-dae)
DISPLAY=:0  (unity-lens-vide)
DISPLAY=:0  (zeitgeist-daemo)
DISPLAY=:0  (zeitgeist-fts)
DISPLAY=:0  (zeitgeist-datah)
DISPLAY=:0  (cat)
DISPLAY=:0  (unity-scope-vid)
DISPLAY=:0  (unity-musicstor)
DISPLAY=:0  (dconf-service)
DISPLAY=:0  (gdu-notificatio)
DISPLAY=:0  (telepathy-indic)
DISPLAY=:0  (mission-control)
DISPLAY=:0  (goa-daemon)
DISPLAY=:0  (VBoxXPCOMIPCD)
```

To explain what's going on, this loop searches recursively in the `/proc` directory searching for `DISPLAY` in each file. Those files are really the processes running, so every file containing the word DISPLAY means that this process is using it.

Comment: Nice solution. Could you please add some explanation for what happens behind the scene? Also, the output is cropt, what can I do to get full process names?

Comment: This command search recursively in the the /proc directory. grep for the `DISPLAY` in each file. Those files are in really the processes running so every file containing the word `DISPLAY` means that this process is using it. You can't get the full process name since the names in the output are the file names founded ion `/proc` so simply you can't know more than the offered.

Comment: PLease, edit your answer instead and just inform the user that you have updated your post.

Comment: I had messed up the DISPLAY env variable and wanted to know what were the values of DISPLAY before I changed it, I don't know of any commad which could tell me about its history, so by using this command i found which earlier processes had used which DISPLAY value and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, all the current processes that correspond to the programs that you execute on the local machine, post login, are gonna carry the same display variable as your first open pts (pseudo-terminal session) console.

For instance, when you open your first terminal session (gnome-terminal) and run the who or w command you will notice some output like this:

```
$ who

yourusername   :0        2015-06-08 14:05 (:0)
yourusername   pts/0     2015-06-08 14:22 (:0)
```

or some folks might look like this (but not it your case)

```
yourusername   :0        2015-06-08 14:05 (:0)
yourusername   pts/0     2015-06-08 14:22 (:0.0)
```

using the light display manager if the DISPLAY variable is set differently for post login execution of shells (e.g. :0.0), then the environment variable for DISPLAY would yield the same display variable as the post-login display variable of the first open pts (:0.0), but the host variable, at login, would still be (:0).

By echoing the DISPLAY variable, or running set piped to less as shown below:

```
:~$ echo $DISPLAY
```

or

```
:~$ set | less
```

you can also check your sessions current display variable, and see what it is set to, for post login execution of shells. So basically the display variable of the processes you execute are gonna have the same display variable as your first open pts, post login.

The output of the script

```
for file in /proc/[0-9]*; do grep -ao 'DISPLAY=[^[:cntrl:]]*' $file/environ 2>/dev/null && grep -ao '(.*)' $file/stat; done | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
```

that Maythux posted, suggests that your first open pts is gonna have the same display variable as your display manager's login, in this case :0.

Now for the second example, the output would look something like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfs-udisks2-vo)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (zeitgeist-daemo)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (zeitgeist-fts)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (zeitgeist-datah)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfs-mtp-volume)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfs-gphoto2-vo)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfs-afc-volume)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (geyes_applet2)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (indicator-apple)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (cat)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (python)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfsd-trash)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (indicator-keybo)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gvfsd-burn)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (cat) 
DISPLAY=:0.0    (cat)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (gnome-terminal)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (bash)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (bash)
DISPLAY=:0.0    (sed)
```

Also for additional reading you can look at the the man pages for ptmx

```
$ man ptmx
```

This might lend some insight into the master-slave relationship of pseudo-terminals.

Answer (score 1):

With a small modification to the Maythux script, we can also get the PID of the processes using the DISPLAY variable.

```bsh
for file in /proc/[0-9]*; do grep -ao 'DISPLAY=[^[:cntrl:]]*' $file/environ 2>/dev/null && grep -ao '[0-9]* (.*)' $file/stat; done | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/' |column -t |sort -n -k2
```

The output is:

```
DISPLAY=:0  590    (lxsession)
DISPLAY=:0  645    (unclutter)
DISPLAY=:0  705    (gvfsd)
DISPLAY=:0  710    (gvfsd-fuse)
DISPLAY=:0  727    (openbox)
DISPLAY=:0  729    (lxpolkit)
DISPLAY=:0  732    (lxpanel)
DISPLAY=:0  734    (pcmanfm)
DISPLAY=:0  772    (menu-cached)
DISPLAY=:0  781    (gvfs-udisks2-vo)
DISPLAY=:0  791    (gvfs-gphoto2-vo)
DISPLAY=:0  795    (gvfs-mtp-volume)
DISPLAY=:0  799    (gvfs-afc-volume)
DISPLAY=:0  804    (gvfs-goa-volume)
DISPLAY=:0  816    (gvfsd-trash)
DISPLAY=:0  21053  (npm)
DISPLAY=:0  21102  (sh)
DISPLAY=:0  21103  (sh)
DISPLAY=:0  21104  (node)
DISPLAY=:0  21110  (electron)
DISPLAY=:0  21112  (electron)
DISPLAY=:0  21149  (electron)
DISPLAY=:0  21154  (electron)
DISPLAY=:0  21180  (rec)
```