# I can't run IDLE on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, idle

I can't get idle to run on my linux system. I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle3", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1544, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1871, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run this command :`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

For more details, you can read this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/432257/540282)

Comment: Hi, I tried it but still having issues. See below: aellis@JBCOSYSLOG:/$ idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1553, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "0.0"
aellis@JBCOSYSLOG:/$

Comment: Could you try export DISPLAY=:0