# What exactly does DISPLAY localhost mean?

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, display

I am trying to do some X11 forwarding and I got completely lost. I found very good answers explaining the theory:

- [What is the $DISPLAY environment variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine
- https://superuser.com/questions/368530/understanding-x-windows-display-environment-variable-when-tunnelling

But I'm still straggling when applying it in practice.

Here is what I did:

1. Opened `mobaxterm` which creates a X server on my machine (Windows, shouldn't matter).
2. `ssh -X server1`
3. `echo $DISPLAY` gives `localhost:10.0`
4. `xeyes` - opens a window on my local machine. Great, but why does `localhost` direct to my machine? Shouldn't it be `server1`?

As far as I understand `localhost` is equal to `127.0.0.1` which is the local address. So if I'm connected to `server1` shouldn't it look for X-server on `server1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens exactly because you perform X11 **forwarding** (or perhaps could be called X11 *tunneling*).

You could fire up an X server, connect to a remote host, and on that remote host set $DISPLAY to point back to your original computer. In that case (if network, permissions etc. are set up correctly) your graphical app would try to connect to your desktop to present its window there, *independently* from your existing ssh connection, and accordingly, probably over an unencrypted channel.

Instead, what happens is that your application believes that it presents the window on the same computer, and unaware to that application, `ssh` catches that and directs the actions back to your original computer, under its own encrypted channel.

One advantage of this method is that the traffic is encrypted. Another advantage is that you don't have to enable others (with proper authentication, access control) to connect to your machine, plus it even works if your local machine is unaddressable from the remote one (e.g. is behind a firewall, or on a private network etc.).

Comment: +1 ... so to be specific, `localhost` in this context refers to the loopback address of the *remote* machine - as explained under `X11UseLocalhost` in the `sshd_config` man page

Comment: Wow. I can't think of anything but "I love you".