Virtual box: how to open and command a terminal on the guest VM from the HOST (Ubuntu)
I am working with several Ubuntu Virtual Machines with VBox (Version 7.0.18 r162988 (Qt5.15.3)) on a Ubuntu host. My goal is to be able to open a terminal on the VM from a terminal of the host, and eventually run commands/scripts on it. The network settings of the VM are based on a NAT connection with host port number 2200 and guest port 22. I am able to connect to the VM via ssh using
ssh -X -p 2200 name@localhost.
Once I log in I can run commands as normal, however I want to run a simulator on the VM with multiple graphic windows, and while the code is correctly compiled and the application is launched, I cannot display it anywhere.
What I am basically trying to do is to find a way to open a terminal on the guest VM via a terminal on the host, instead of connecting via ssh and making the terminal of the host as if it is a terminal of the guest.
The idea is to establish a sort of remote desktop connection to the VM, however I have no idea on how to set it up without installing too much software (the host is a shared server).

Ubuntu GNOME comes with an integrated RDP server, which you can turn on in Settings / System / Remote Desktop (on 24.04, on previous versions I believe you would find the option under Settings / Sharing). Could that suffice? You'd just need to install an RDP client on the client (maybe Remmina, although last time I checked its 24.04 release was broken to say the least)

You can also look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable/919913#919913
