# `xcalib -i -a` controls only one of two screens - can it control both?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, screen, xcalib

I am using 2 screens, and wish to invert the colors on both of them without using compiz (I'm using gnome shell).

I can use `xcalib -invert -alter` as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181419/how-to-reverse-colors-for-the-current-window-in-gnome-shell#comment233918_185029), but it only inverts one of the screens. Is there a way to specify both of them, or even which of them, using `xcalib`? Is there another way?

With `xcalib`, you can specify which screen to alter with the `-d` (`-display`) or `-s` (`-screen`) options, but alas, `X` seems to be aware of just one screen: when I use the [`w` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230835/list-existing-x-display-names) I only see one (the usual ":0")

ps: this question was originally posted by [k0pernikus](https://askubuntu.com/users/32792/k0pernikus) as a comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181419/how-to-reverse-colors-for-the-current-window-in-gnome-shell#comment233918_185029).

---edit---

This is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
1280x1024 60.0*+ 75.0
1280x960 60.0
1152x864 75.0
1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0
832x624 74.6
800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2
640x480 72.8 75.0 66.7 60.0
720x400 70.1
DVI-0 connected 1920x1200+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200 60.0*+
1600x1200 60.0
1280x1024 75.0 60.0
1280x960 60.0
1152x864 75.0
1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0
832x624 74.6
800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2
640x480 72.8 75.0 66.7 60.0
720x400 70.1
```

I can use `-s DVI-0` or `-s VGA-0`, but they do the same as `-s :0`

Comment: I have the same problem.  There are some commands in my ticket that may help you add some information to your ticket.  Lets see if we have a similar setup: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118477/what-is-the-xcalib-screen-number-for-the-vga-monitor-when-the-other-monitor-is

Comment: I have a work-around... It got more complicated with Ubuntu 14.04.  Basically, I invert once (one screen) using `-s 0` the I unplug and re-plug my HDMI cable.  Then I invert again (same screen same command).. Finally I invert `-s HDMI-0`.. and both monitors are inverted.  I can then toggle one of them with the -s 0.  So, aside from this being so ridiculous this holds me over.

Comment: lol! I once collected a data set from a dynamic website by putting a weight on the 'page-down' key, waiting till memory was all filled up, then hitting ctrl-s (very carefully - the machine was almost completely unresponsive!)

Answer (score 4):

No.

> Note that as of date of last testing (2014, xcalib version 0.8) xcalib
>   has not been able to invert the colors on all monitors in a
>   multi-monitor setup, because all monitors are presented by the X11
>   server as a single screen. Thus this limitation is coming from the X11
>   server. xrandr-invert-colors does not have this limitation, because it
>   uses XRandR API, which correctly handles all attached monitors.

from here: https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors

Comment: I have searched for this comment for a very long time. `xcalib` doesn't work on one of my monitors, so I was suffering along trying to put light-on-dark windows only on that monitor, etc. Thank you so much for this suggestion! I have no idea how I haven't seen it long ago.

Answer (score 1):

The display ids in X follow the form `:<screen>.<display>`. Contrary to intuition, all the monitors in a multiple-monitor setup share a `<screen>`, but have varying `<display>`. The screen "first" in the setup is `:0.0`, and others are `:0.1`, `:0.2`, etc. The final command is `xcalib -invert -alter -display :0.1`

Comment: nice try, but on `:0.0` is recognized (same screen as `:0`), the others I tried all said something like `Error - Can't open display :0.1`

Comment: Could you try `:1`, and the like?

Comment: no luck ):  Only thing I can find that works is `:0` or `:0.0` (which are the same monitor). I wonder if Gnome is not playing fair with X??

Comment: hmmmm... What is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: 'Can't open display' ... that's it! Gnome is doing somthing these tools don't expect!

Comment: No, gnome isn't the problem. Gnome is a [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), whereas [X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is the backend for everything going to the screen.

Comment: Could you tell me if the two screens are mirrored?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13981/discussion-between-drevicko-and-user269370)

Comment: did you guys find a solution after all? Having the same problem

Comment: @IHeartAndroid: No, we didn't. You seem to be the third person (here) to have the issue, so it *may* be ready for a launchpad bug report.

Comment: @user269370 I also have this issue with 14.04

Comment: I have the issue. I'm using archlinux, but the same ol x.org (and xcalib). xcalib is a *very* simple application, and it's clear that it wasn't written with multiple monitors in mind. I'll look into contributing an enhancement.

Comment: any updates on this issue? I am also interested in a solution to invert multiple screens (built-in plus dp-connected) running xcalib 0.9 on manjaro. ---- after writing this, I found the answer of @python which suggests to use xrandr-invert-colors as an alternative to xcalib. it works fine

Answer (score 0):

`xcalib`'s `-screen` parameter takes the zero based integer index of the screen, ie, in your case `0` for `VGA-0` and `1` for `DVI-0`.